# Get sentence(s) which include(s) searched word(s)?

Tags: php, get

I want to get sentence(s) which include(s) searched word(s). I have tried this but can't make it work properly.

```
$string = "I think instead of trying to find sentences, I'd think about the amount of 
context around the search term I would need in words. Then go backwards some fraction of this number of words (or to the beginning) and forward the remaining number 
of words to select the rest of the context.";

$searchlocation = "fraction";

$offset = stripos( strrev(substr($string, $searchlocation)), '. ');
$startloc = $searchlocation - $offset;
echo $startloc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all sentences.

try this:

```
$string = "I think instead of trying to find sentences, I'd think about the amount of 
context around the search term I would need in words. Then go backwards some fraction of this number of words (or to the beginning) and forward the remaining number 
of words to select the rest of the context.";

$searchlocation = "fraction";

$sentences = explode('.', $string);
$matched = array();
foreach($sentences as $sentence){
    $offset = stripos($sentence, $searchlocation);
    if($offset){ $matched[] = $sentence; }
}
var_export($matched);
```

Answer (score 2):

using [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) function

```
$sentences = explode('.', $string);
$result = array_filter(
    $sentences, 
    create_function('$x', "return strpos(\$x, '$searchlocation');"));
```

Note: the double quote in the second parameter of `create_function` is necessary.

If you have anonymous function support, you can use this,

```
$result = array_filter($sentences, function($x) use($searchlocation){
        return strpos($x, $searchlocation)!==false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you reverse the string with `strrev()`, you will find `[space].` instead of `.[space]`.