# Find a sentence that contains a word in text from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to explain what I am trying to accomplish with an example. Let's assume I have two rows in my `posts` table.

```
It snows a lot in winter in Norway. While it barely snows where I live.

I run four miles every morning. I am trying to get fit.
```

When I search `in winter` I want to get the sentence `It snows a lot in winter in Norway.`

I know I can get the row with:

```
$posts = \App\Models\Post::where('body', 'like', "%{in winter}%")->get();
```

But I am not sure how to get the exact sentence.

Comment: curly brackets seems to be excess. `.. "%in winter%" ..`

Comment: Unless you are tracking individual sentences as fields, once you get your entity out you'll need to do the rest with just straight PHP. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239752/231316

Comment: Laravel has methods to get specific column values, but the correct method depends on which version of Laravel you are using.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i am using laravel 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it might be technically possible using `SQL` to get the exact sentence, you are better off using PHP for getting the exact sentence from the collection.

I have created an example using collections (since you're using Laravel), starting with your provided Post query (although I did remove the curly braces from the like string).

**1. Get the collection of posts with body like search query**

```
$posts = Post::where('body', 'like', "%in winter%")->get();
```

**2. Map collection of posts to individual sentences. Flatten to remove empty sentences.**

```
$postSentences = $posts->map( function($post) {
   // preg split makes sure the text is splitted on . or ! or ?
   return preg_split('/\.|\?|!/', $post->body); 
})->flatten();
```

**3. Get the corresponding sentence(s) using a filter and Str::contains()**

```
$matchingSentences = $postSentences->filter( function($sentence) {
    return Str::contains($sentence, 'in winter');
});
```

`$matchingSentences` should return:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection 
    all: [
       "It snows a lot in winter in Norway",
    ],
}
```

The example can probably be altered / shortened to your fitting. But this should solve the aforementioned problem.